# php http tunnel to mysql connection

Tags: mysql, php, http, tunneling

How to create a HTTP tunnel to PHP to MySQL connection

Comment: why http? most people tunnel through stunnel (encrypted) or ssh.

Comment: I'm not very versed in this area. I think that I do not need encryption. I just want to connect to mysql on hosting. Through the standard port 3306 does not work, since it is closed. And I want to connect to mysql through a port 80 through the tunnel. How can I do tell me if you can, I will be grateful.

Answer (score 0):

If you have PHP on the host, you may try using Navicat. (Trial and non-commercial versions are also available.) Take a look to navicat.com.

Once you install Navicat, a php file will be placed among the binaries of the app. Then you have to copy it to your host. When setting up the MySQL server connection in Navicat, go to the HTTP tab, enable HTTP tunneling, and enter the URL of the php put on the host. The IP/port/user/password of your MySql server need to be entered into Navicat as usual. (Set IP as it is seen from the Host on which the php script is running)

It's done.